# Object 'err' is of type unknown

Tags: typescript, async-await, try-catch

So I am looking at some code for a backend and I noticed anywhere that a method has `async` in front of it, inside the `try/catch` statement TypeScript complains about the `err` object, saying `Object 'err' is unknown`, but that does not occur for methods that are synchronous.

```
async createOrganization(dbSession: ClientSession, organization: IOrganization): Promise<IOrganization> {
    try {
      // @ts-ignore
      const newOrganization = new this.Model(organization)
      // @ts-ignore
      await newOrganization.save()
      // @ts-ignore
      return newOrganization
    } catch (err) {
      throw new OrganizationCreationError(err.message)
    }
  }
```

What is it about utilizing the `try/catch` inside an asynchronous method that makes that `err` object be unknown and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The catch clause variable was historically typed as `any`, but since [TypeScript 4.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#use-unknown-catch-variables) under the `strict` compiler option (or the new `useUnknownInCatchVariables` option) it is now typed as `unknown`. It has nothing to do with methods being anynchronous.

If you aren't seeing this error in some other parts of your codebase that fall under the same TypeScript version and compiler options, a few possible reasons come to mind:

- The catch clause variable isn't being used in a way incompatible with the `unknown` type, perhaps it's being passed to a function that accepts an `unknown` or `any` typed parameter.
- The catch clause variable is explicitly typed as `any`.